# How does iOS remove multiple observer on same object

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

When I developed the KVO behaviour,

```
[A addObserver:B forKeyPath:kLAShopRuleObserveKey options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

And I removed the observer in `[B dealloc]` as:

```
[A removeObserver:B forKeyPath:kObserveKey];
```

It works fine.

Now I add the observer multiple times:

```
[A addObserver:B forKeyPath:kLAShopRuleObserveKey options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[A addObserver:B forKeyPath:kLAShopRuleObserveKey options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

But I only remove the KVO once in B:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [A removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kObserveKey];
}
```

it works fine on iOS 11 and later, but crashes on iOS 10 and earlier,
how it behaves differently

Answer (score 0):

In [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide: Registering as an Observer](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-178352), they point out that you should use the `context` parameter.

So, define your contexts:

```
static void *observerContext = &observerContext;
static void *observerContext2 = &observerContext2;
```

Then use these contexts when adding the observers:

```
[a addObserver:b forKeyPath:kLAShopRuleObserveKey options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:observerContext];
[a addObserver:b forKeyPath:kLAShopRuleObserveKey options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:observerContext2];
```

Then use these contexts when removing the observers:

```
[a removeObserver:b forKeyPath:kLAShopRuleObserveKey context:observerContext];
[a removeObserver:b forKeyPath:kLAShopRuleObserveKey context:observerContext2];
```

This removes any ambiguity. It should also work regardless of iOS version.

---

By the way, your `observeValueForKeyPath` should be checking the context parameter, and calling `super` rendition if it doesn’t match.

E.g. if you have separate handlers:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == observerContext) {
        // handle observer 1
    } else if (context == observerContext2) {
        // handle observer 2
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

Or, if both are doing the same thing:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == observerContext || context == observerContext2) {
        // handle observer
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

This pattern helps avoid problems that might arise if your key happened to match the same key used by some superclass.